# EqualityComparer<T>.Default misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, iequalitycomparer

I have a class `Person`, it implements Equals() method from `IEquatable<Person>` (also overrides `Object.Equals` method, lets ignore the GetHashcode() method for now)

```
class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return this.Name == other.Name;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var person = obj as Person;
        return person != null && person.Name == Name;
    }
}
```

Ok, lets start:

```
Person p1 = new Person() { Name = "a" };
Person p2 = new Person() { Name = "a" };

List<Person> lst1 = new List<Person>() { p1 };
List<Person> lst2 = new List<Person>() { p2 };
```

Lets talk about this line :

```
 bool b = lst1.SequenceEqual(lst2, EqualityComparer<Person>.Default);
```

I have a problem understanding this part :

```
EqualityComparer<Person>.Default
```

I've heard that `EqualityComparer<Person>.Default` will check if the class is implementing `IEquatable` - it will take the `Equals(Person other)` Method and not the `Equals(object obj)`. **it has the advantage of avoiding boxing**

[image]
**but**

the `Equals(Person other)` will run **with or withOUT** `EqualityComparer<Person>.Default`
(because it's implementing IEquatable)

So what Boxing are we talking about ?  there isn't !

The only time that  `Equals(object obj)` will run is when :

```
bool b = lst1.SequenceEqual(lst2,EqualityComparer<Object>.Default);
```

**But** I'm a programmer! I'll never Send an `object` when its actually a `Person`!

What am I missing? I'm having trouble understanding the benefit here of `EqualityComparer<Object>.Default`. Can someone please give me an example to prove me I'm wrong ?

Comment: What do you not understand? The benefit of instantiating `IEqualityComparer<Object>.Default`, or why you can choose a specific instantiation, or something else?

Comment: why does it work with or withOUT  it , and why do i have a reason to call it with<object> type

Comment: Boxing only happens for value types. Since `Person` is a reference type, there is no boxing involved in this case.

Comment: @thecoop you cant do `bool b = lst1.SequenceEqual(lst2,EqualityComparer<int>.Default);` becuase it requires : Tsource type. and the Tsource is Person.

Comment: Looks like there's a big misunderstanding of what's going on. Probably better if we take this to the C# chatroom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass in `null` as the second parameter or if you don't pass in a second argument at all (which is basically the same), the implementation of SequenceEquals will call `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` itself (decompile `Enumerable` to see this). That explains why you don't see a difference whether you provide `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` or not.

So in the end the second parameter only makes sense if you want to use an equality comparer *other than* `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

Comment: why would I ever will use to compare with <T2> when its actually <T> ?

Comment: You might want to implement your own IEqualityComparer<T>,  for example if you use it for a T that doesn't implement equality the way you need it.

Comment: I was told only on value type  - so i guess i have to build a struct

Comment: I don't seem to understand. Please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

That you can pass in `IEqualityComparer<object>.Default` is an effect of [generic contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), added in .NET 4.

Essentially, an `IEqualityComparer<BaseType>` can be used whenever an `IEqualityComparer<DerivedType>` is required, where `DerivedType : BaseType`. Since `Person` derives from `Object`, this means that an `IEqualityComparer<Object>` can be used wherever an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` is required.

Comment: this is because its `contravariant`. why would i want to use object  comparer when its a Person ? Also, Ive heard that it has the advantage of avoiding boxing. which boxing ? something like : "if you have the Iequatable Equals method - I will use it and not The Object.Equals method"....where is that here ?

Comment: In this particular example, generic contravariance isn't really that useful, however there are situations in which it is very useful indeed. Just because you are able to do something doesn't mean that it is right or correct to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx

> For a value type, you should always implement IEquatable and override Object.Equals(Object) for better performance. Object.Equals boxes value types and relies on reflection to compare two values for equality. Both your implementation of Equals and your override of Object.Equals should return consistent results.

If you do not override Equals and GetHashCode, EqualityComparer.Default actually takes care of that for you.